# Postfix Rate Limit - Anvil Service

Tags: postfix

I am trying to rate-limit (add delay) if say 100 emails come in 1 minute interval. Those emails are from a legitimate source and it's not spam, we sometimes get it if the network goes down and would like to add a delay to not overload a mail server. From other blogs, I see postfix with anvil can do that but for some reason, it's not working for me. Here are the parameters I used in main.cf

```
anvil_rate_time_unit = 30s
anvil_status_update_time = 60s
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 2
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 2
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 5
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 2
```

Note: I used lower values just for testing purposes.

May I know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `postfix check` shows no errors?

Comment: No it retuns empty.